# Console.log of typescript is not printing anything on console

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, api, visual-studio-code

I'm using visual code for typescript node.js coding & I don't understand why it's only just printing the server start message i.e. "The server is running on port 6060" & that's it. After this I'm hitting the server with http GET requests, but I'm not getting any logs on my visual studio code terminal which I have put in code explicitly to debug. Below is my code of
**Routes.ts**

```
/** source/routes/posts.ts */
import express from 'express';
import controller from '../controllers/posts';
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/posts', controller.getPosts);
router.get('/posts/:id', controller.getPost);
router.get('/posts?id=:id', controller.getPostID);
router.put('/posts/:id', controller.updatePost);
router.delete('/posts/:id', controller.deletePost);
router.post('/posts', controller.addPost);

export = router;
```

**Posts.ts**;

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';

interface Post {
    userId: Number;
    id: Number;
    title: String;
    body: String;
}

// getting all posts
const getPosts = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    // get some posts
    console.log("look 1");
    let result: AxiosResponse = await axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`);
    let posts: [Post] = result.data;
    return res.status(200).json({
        message: posts
    });
};

// getting a single post
const getPost = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    // get the post id from the req
    let id: string = req.params.id;
    // get the post
    console.log("look 2");
    let result: AxiosResponse = await axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`);
    let post: Post = result.data;
    return res.status(200).json({
        message: post
    });
};

//query a particular post
const getPostID = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    // get the post id from the req
    //let id: string = req.query.id;
    let id: string = req.params.id;
    console.log("look 3");
    // get the post
    let result: AxiosResponse = await axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`,{
        params: {
          id: 5
        }
      });
    let post: Post = result.data;
    return res.status(200).json({
        message: post
    });
};

// updating a post
const updatePost = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    // get the post id from the req.params
    let id: string = req.params.id;
    // get the data from req.body
    let title: string = req.body.title ?? null;
    let body: string = req.body.body ?? null;
    // update the post
    let response: AxiosResponse = await axios.put(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`, {
        ...(title && { title }),
        ...(body && { body })
    });
    // return response
    return res.status(200).json({
        message: response.data
    });
};

// deleting a post
const deletePost = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    // get the post id from req.params
    let id: string = req.params.id;
    // delete the post
    let response: AxiosResponse = await axios.delete(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`);
    // return response
    return res.status(200).json({
        message: 'post deleted successfully'
    });
};

// adding a post
const addPost = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    // get the data from req.body
    let title: string = req.body.title;
    let body: string = req.body.body;
    // add the post
    let response: AxiosResponse = await axios.post(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`, {
        title,
        body
    });
    // return response
    return res.status(200).json({
        message: response.data
    });
};

export default { getPosts, getPost, getPostID, updatePost, deletePost, addPost };
```

As you can see I have put console.logs like:- console.log("look 2"). I have already tried it with single quotes.There is no effect; It is just not getting printed.
Below is my **Server.ts** code:-

```
/** source/server.ts */
import http from 'http';
import express, { Express } from 'express';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import routes from './routes/posts';

const router: Express = express();

/** Logging */
router.use(morgan('dev'));
/** Parse the request */
router.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
/** Takes care of JSON data */
router.use(express.json());

/** RULES OF OUR API */
router.use((req, res, next) => {
    // set the CORS policy
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    // set the CORS headers
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'origin, X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept, Authorization');
    // set the CORS method headers
    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET PATCH DELETE POST');
        return res.status(200).json({});
    }
    next();
});

/** Routes */
router.use('/', routes);

/** Error handling */
router.use((req, res, next) => {
    const error = new Error('not found');
    return res.status(404).json({
        message: error.message
    });
});

/** Server */
const httpServer = http.createServer(router);
const PORT: any = process.env.PORT ?? 6060;
httpServer.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`The server is running on port ${PORT}`));
```

As you can see above this server starting log is getting printed.
Please help me to find what's the issue.

Comment: `router.use('/', routes);` I didn't ever see this syntax. Are you sure it's correct? You never define endpoints

Comment: I have followed this link;- https://www.section.io/engineering-education/how-to-create-a-simple-rest-api-using-typescript-and-nodejs/     --- & I am able to successfully hit the url & get the response .But, my issue is precisely about console.log not printing anything on console

Comment: You missed entire file `routes/posts.ts` where endpoints are assigned. Or you didn't included it here

Comment: I didn't put it here...Fine I will put that also since you have mentioned

Comment: I see you are using https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan.  Are you sure it's not intercepting console output?  Try removing it temporarily as it's just a logger.

Comment: With Morgan  I am able to get the log on vscode console as what url  what method of my API got hit by POSTMAN. Without Morgan , I am not getting this details also...So morgan is not creating any issue.. It is good .Issue is something else

Comment: You said the requests were working fine.  What happens if you deliberately break one (or change the output) and the hit the endpoint?  Does the breakage/change show up as expected?

Comment: Also I noticed you were using TypeScript, not JS.  Do you have some sort of precompile step that translates from TS into JS?

Comment: I got the answer guys .. Actually after making any changes to typescript code .I need to run tsc command everytime so that it transpiles in to js code everytime & keeps it fresh. & then when I run npm run dev ...It can print console.log... But Here I'm wondering that nodemon  is just starting the server as soon as I make changes in file.. & it is not running tsc command to update the nodejs  file in background & therefore it is not getting the latest console log changes... Does anyone know how to solve this issue.

Comment: nodemon isn't aware of your TypeScript build process.  Id suggest you run tsc with the --watch flag and leave it running while you are developing code.  It will detect TS changes and compile to JS, and then nodemon will reload.